# logging.config in application.properties gets not picked up

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, war, application.properties

currently, I am working on a Spring Boot application that I bundle and deploy as a war to a Tomcat Servlet Container.

I want to configure log4j2. When I include a file named log4j2.xml the configuration works.
However, I want to make it flexible. Therefore, I include

```
logging.config=file:C:\\Users\\...\\log4j2-configuration.xml
```

into application.properties. But then the configuration is not picked up.
I want for development purposes another logging configuration than for production this is why I want to specify the configuration in the application.properties

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>[...]</groupId>
<artifactId>[...]</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For generating classes from xsd -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--logging-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean package jboss-as:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/applicationdata-database</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2.x location can be specified as either an [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) or a file path. Invalid URIs recognized by Java's [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) are also supported.

The location you are using (`file:C:\\Users\\...\\log4j2-configuration.xml`) is neither a valid `file` URI nor a file name. Try with:

```
logging.config=file:///C:/Users/.../log4j2-configuration.xml
```

or

```
logging.config=C:\\Users\\...\\log4j2-configuration.xml
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the both are working. I had tried the second version before. I am really confused why it does not work. Probably, I am missing something else.

Comment: You should run your application with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and update your question.

Comment: I started the tomcat with the mentioned paramet however, there is nothing in the logs that indicates as to why the configuration xml does not get picked up. I seems as if the property is completely ignored.

Comment: If Spring does not configure Log4j2 correctly you can set `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=C:\Users\...\log4j2-configuration.xml` directly.